# Laravel RESTAPI, show debug froms server side

Tags: laravel, api, debugging, server

I have a web build with laravel as server side with rest api.
and some user will access my restapi

and i want to show debug from server side, if client try to connect/post data to my api

can someone explain to me? or if tutorial that i can follow?

Comment: If I understood your question properly then laravel provides log file located at 'storage/logs' directory. If anything else needed, please specify.

Comment: yes, but its update when error happened, what i want is when success/error will save in something like log file, any package in laravel?

Comment: You can check it - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use any of the following.

```
Log::emergency("Your message");
Log::alert("Your message");
Log::critical("Your message");
Log::error("Your message");
Log::warning("Your message");
Log::notice("Your message");
Log::info("Your message");
Log::debug("Your message");
```

It will store the log in your log file. It will be better to set the `LOG_CHANNEL=daily`. If you have a slack channel then you can get your Log notification in that channel.

To learn more about logging please go through this official doc.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging

Answer (score 1):

To capture all errors apart from logged messages , with its stack trace you can try for laravel package

[rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer)

This is more convenient to debug the issues .